# Jenkins - Building the project across different compiler versions

Tags: jenkins, combinations

I am using Jenkins for a build test

I have an RTL/C project which must be tested across 3 different RTL simulator versions, lets call them RTL1, RTL2, RTL3 (all of them installed on the build machine). I also need to check them across 3 different GCC versions - call it GCC1, GCC2, GCC3 (these are installed too).

There are 9 combinations to test => RTL1-GCC1 thru RTL3-GCC3

How can I achieve this in Jenkins ?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [matrix projects](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project)

One axis would be your 3 RTL simulators and the other axis would be GCC versions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the solution is to use properties to inject environment variables.
The only weird thing is that it does not take "export" or "setenv"